# Set Cookie in Javascript returns undefined while value exists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I am having a textarea in which i use ACE Editor to have syntax highlight. I get the value from the editor onchange. Then i want to set the value to a cookie and then retrieve the cookie in PHP but it always gives me null.

My Code:

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="comment">Translation:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="15"  id="translation" name="editor_data"><?=$file;?></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="komutdosyasi" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right" name="save">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the javascript code:

```
<script>
        var editor = ace.edit("translation");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/php");
        editor.resize();
        editor.setOptions({
            maxLines: 35
        });
        editor.on("change", function () {
           var value = editor.getSession().getValue();
           var v = setCookie('editor_data', value);
           var x = getCookie('editor_data');
           console.log('Cookie: ' + x);
        });

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; ";
        }

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
```

All the jquery and editor scripts are loaded in the  tag.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you get data in the onchange handler? ie: `var value = editor.getSession().getValue();`

Comment: yes i do...and this is the weird thing...i do them and then when i console log the cookie that i set it says null

Comment: Please notice that if you're testing this locally using `localhost`, the cookie won't be set at all.

Comment: i am testing on a live server

Comment: is it maybe because of the text size? because i read now that the size of the cookie should be 4096 bytes max and i try to set a very large text. PHP Code actually currently(225lines)

Comment: @BRG Yes, that's definitely a problem. You may want to try to set `editor_data` to a very short string on the PHP side, just to see if it works as expected. But you'll have to do it differently anyway.

Comment: yes of course it works with a smaller string.

Comment: How many lines do yo have?

Comment: 225 lines read above comment please, and will add even more

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with storage. Try using local storage instead of cookies as it is faster and can hold more data. Only do this if you only need to access the data from the client side.

This webpage has very good info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: local storage does not help because i wanted data from the server side this is why i wanted to do it with COOKIE because then i can retrieve from php as $_COOKIE. So i used ajax to post to php